# Converting an NSArray component into an integer or decimal number

Tags: ios, integer, plot, nsarray

I have a case where the data read from the CSV file in the app has to be converted into an integer, has to be plotted later. Currently it doesn't recognize when the data is saved as

```
int i=[[rows objectAtIndex:0] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

This is the implemented code.

```
-(void)connection :(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{

    [self serverConnect];
    response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //NSLog(response);

    NSString *stripped1 = [response stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\r" withString:@""];
    NSArray *rows = [stripped1 componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

    NSArray *components;

    for (int i=0;i<[rows count]; i++) {
         if(i == 0 || [[rows objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@""]){
             continue;
         }
        components = [[rows objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
        NSLog(@"data1:%@ data2:%@ data3:%@", [components objectAtIndex:0] ,[components objectAtIndex:1],[components objectAtIndex:2]);
    }
```

`data1`, `data2` and `data3` are supposed to be integers.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

componentsSeparatedByString returns substrings, or instances of NSString.

```
         components = [[rows objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

You just need to take each member of 'components' and get it's intValue, like so:

```
int myInt = [[components objectAtIndex:n] intValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

NSArray and NSMutableArray can only contains objects. So get the integer value from it, use [object intValue]. If you need to add an integer to an array, create a NSNumber object from the integer and insert it. I know Rayfleck answered your question and i just want to point out the way how array works in iOS. Hope this helps.